# How to "clean" string readed from file()

Tags: php

I have a program that read a txt file that have a format (this is a specification, i cant use JSON for some reason): 
key:value
key2:value2
key3:value2
etc  
And after read it (i use file()) i put the key-value pair into an associative array (for example $settings). but for some reason when i trying to read first value using $settings["key"] ("key" is first line in the txt file), it returns error that "key" is undefined index. But when i print the $settings array using print_r, "key" is definitely there. This error happens only when using "key"  ("key2","key3" works fine). When i check the length of the "key" that used for associative array key, it returns 6 (should be 3). 
 
Here is my PHP File Program:

```
$readsetting = array();
session_start();
$setting = "users_setting/".$_SESSION['userID'].".txt";
$myfile1 = file($setting);
if(!$myfile1){
    $setting = "users_setting/default.txt";
    $myfile1 = file($setting);
}
if ($myfile1){
    foreach($myfile1 as $name){
      $x = explode(":",$name);
      if (isset($x[0])&&isset($x[1])){
        $readsetting[trim($x[0])] = trim($x[1]);
        echo strlen($x[0]);
    }
 }


 echo $readsetting["type0"];
 print_r($readsetting);
```

[Here is the result when trying the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh5Os.png)

How to fix this?